# Why doesn't this while loop work as a substitute for this try/except block when checking the availability of modules?

Tags: python, while-loop, pip

The following works as intended installing the module before importing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run
from sys import modules
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except:
    run("pip3 install beautifulsoup4", shell=True)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It crossed my mind that I could accomplish the same job with a while loop.
And so I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run
from sys import modules

while "bs4" not in modules:# neither does  work `while not "bs4" in modules:`
    run("pip3 install beautifulsoup4", shell=True)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

But it does not work, I get from Python:

```
/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.11.1
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
```

Comment: `sys.modules` is a cache of modules that have been imported by your program not a directory of available modules. You need to import the module for it to be present in `sys.modules`

Comment: Even if you will somehow manage to implement automatic module installation, better not. Make a setup script or let user install all requirements manually, that's a proper way.

Comment: You script shouldn't be responsible for installing missing modules. It's the installer's job to ensure that any prerequisites are available.

Comment: You would want to use an `if` statement anyway; the two most expected outcomes for the loop would be for it to execute the body exactly once (like the `if` statement) or try and fail to install the package forever (hardly useful behavior for your script).

Comment: The way to *find* a module (without necessarily installing it) would be to use `importlib.find_loader`, which will either return the loader object that `import` would use to actually load the module, or `None` if no loader can be found.